# How can I change accidentally wrong written date into the previous number form?

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAJle.png)---->Currently I am working on a data which has more than 26 million rows and 2 columns. I managed to seperate it into equal sized - 1 million csv files. The problem here is - I need to open this file in Python and plot the graph of the data. But some rows of the data was accidentally written in date format. (For example-It was desired to write 11.1118 celsius but instead excel got 11/11/2018)There are too many rows that I need to fix and I can't do it one by one. Is there any solution to this or..?

Given above is the part of my data and there are hundreds of same mistakes in the upcoming rows

Comment: refer how to ask question on Stackoverflow

Comment: Have u tried format column cells with `General` instead of default `Date` within excel itself by right click on a column, and then read data with `xlrd` and search what u want with module `re`?

Comment: @LauReal I have tried but when I format cells with General,I number 49567(f.e.) which is obviously not the thing that I am looking for

Comment: Can u upload a demo excel so that others may do debug.

Comment: Where does the data come from and how did the data come into Excel?

Comment: With that amount of data, use a different program...

Answer (score 0):

If the image you posted is representative for the whole problem you have, I think you do not have any problem, because only the left column is corrupted and as far as I can see this column shows nothing but an equidistant list of numbers with step `0.5`. If you need this as an x-value of a diagram you can simply create it separately and import only the data of the right column.